# Mathematics subtraction of an equation?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Would someone tells me where is the error in the equation (ɛ). 
$\frac{d(x)}{(dt)} = \frac{(K∆P)}{φμs[ML+(1-M)x]}$   (2.14)

The velocity of the leading edge of the perturbation is given by :

$\frac{d(x+ɛ)}{(dt)} = \frac{(K∆P)}{φμs[ML+(1-M)(x+ɛ)]}$  (2.15)

```
By subtracting equation (2.15) from (2.14) and provided that ɛ⪡xf:
```

$\frac{d(ɛ)}{(dt)} = \frac{(-K∆P(1-M)ɛ)}{φμs[ML+(1-M)x]^2}$

```
Therefore, ɛ=e^C, where C is:
```

${C} = \frac{(-K∆P(1-M))}{φμs[ML+1-Mx]^2}$

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @MattSamuel thank you very much, taht was really helpful to fix the formatting of teh equation